# Conectar dos aplicaciones diferentes por medio de jobs en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo dos aplicaciones en Laravel y necesito que cuando se ejecute el job de la primera aplicaciones llame a un job de la otra.

Me estuve guiando por este Post [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578850/laravel-common-queue-for-two-projects) pero no obtuve resultados y seguramente estoy equivocandome en algo:

Dentro del proyecto A defino la ruta de ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/jobs-containers', function () {
    dispatch(new JobBeetwenContainers(true))->onQueue('queue-b');
    return 'Dispached Beanstalk Job';
});
```

Esto funciona muy bien y realiza el dispatch al job del proyecto:

```
class JobBeetwenContainers implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $state;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param $state
     */
    public function __construct($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Dispatching potatoes job...');
    }
}
```

Pero en el proyecto B, el cual definí lo mismo, no ingresa al job. Este es:

```
<?php

namespace Potatoes\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class JobBeetwenContainers implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $integratedUser;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param $integratedUser
     */
    public function __construct($integratedUser)
    {
        $this->integratedUser = $integratedUser;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Job from Potatoes!');
    }
}
```

Dentro del proyecto B, también definí la ruta como A:

```
Route::get('/jobs-containers', function () {
    dispatch(new JobBeetwenContainers(true))->onQueue('queue-b');
    return 'Dispached Potatoes Job';
});
```

Una aclaracióm que olvidé, es que cada aplicación se encuentra dentro de un contenedor de docker, pero no sé si esto puede afectar el tema de los jobs.

Comment: en el proyecto b también definiste la ruta?, ambos deben ser espejos en ese aspecto, y debes hacer la petición a ámbos proyectos.

Comment: Probé hacer lo que dijiste y no funciona. El tema de la ruta es para que lance el job nomas, cosa que yo entre a localhost:5000 y ejecute el Job A y este ejecute el Job B, nunca voy a usar la ruta de A, pero ahí actualice el post @zerocool

Comment: Entiendo, el tema es que el job b entonces debería hacer la petición a la ruta de la otra aplicación (A). Más aún si cada aplicación está dockerizada quiere decir que se ejecutan totalmente independiente una de otra, no tienes una manera directa de ejecutar el job de la aplicación A desde la B más que usando esas rutas, al final tienes que usar la ruta de A desde donde la quieras llamar.

Comment: y hay forma de llamarla o tendria que usar un guzzle por ejemplo para hacer la petición a esa ruta? @zerocool